# Django ORM search product but group by category

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am trying to implement a search system which will display all the results by category.

These are my models.

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name="slug",
        allow_unicode=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text='A slug to identify posts by this category',
    )

  
class Product(models.Model):
   

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name=_('Product Name'),
    )
    categories = ManyToManyField("product.Category", related_name="product_category")
```

I need to render all the item group by category in frontend/template but query will be based on product name.

```
prod_cat = Category.objects.annotate(
        filtered_product=Product.objects.filter(name__incontains="My Search Term goes There")
)
```

and it is not working at all.

Also I can query by like this way:

```
result = []
prod_cat = Category.objects.all()
for cat in prod_cat:
    p = cat.product_category.filter(name__incontains='My Another Search Term')
    result.append(p)
```

But I think it is not group by, it's list product based on each list, in that way I can't name the category name on template as category heading.

is there anyone knows about it how I can query and group by each category?

Comment: You say group by category but you want to search products? Is it that you want to perform a **join** as it is called in database terms? A Group by means some aggregation needs to be performed, which is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I want to search product based on the specific terms and all the search result will be displayed based on category.

Comment: As a side note, you need more queries just to do stuff this way (displaying search results in groups according to a many to many). Consider simply displaying the results without grouping by category and giving an option to search a particular category only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current solution would work easily if you change `result.append(p)` as follows:

```
result.append({'category': cat, 'products': p})
```

Now in the template:

```
{% for entry in result %}
    {{ entry.category.name }}
    {% for product in entry.products %}
        {{ product.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```